# Custom attribute instead of val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I never need jQuery for more than I can find on web. I'm trying to do "live" counting of custom html attribute from select/option.

I used this script which is working fine, but unfortunately I need data from value to send it to PHP and need to use custom data- attribute. I don't know how to access option instead of val() - I tried $ksm, $data('ksm') and some other weird ideas, but it won't work.

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
   $(window).load(function(){
    $("[id$=nr]").change(function() {
        var total = 0;     
        $('.zawodnik select').each(function() {
            total = total + Number( $(this).val() );
        });
        $('div#sumaksm').html(total); 
    });
   });
  //]]>
</script>
```

HTML (zaw1 to zaw7 is exactle the same):

```
<tr><td class="zawodnik">
<select name="zaw3" id="3nr">
      <option value="1" class="rider" data-ksm="10.40">Nicki Pedersen (10.40)</option>
      <option value="2" class="rider" data-ksm="9.58">Niels Kristian Iversen (9.58)</option>
      <option value="3" class="rider" data-ksm="9.28">Chris Holder (9.28)</option>
      <option value="4" class="rider" data-ksm="9.27">Greg Hancock (9.27)</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
Your KSM: <div id="sumaksm">-select riders-</div>
```

And I'm sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: To get element data via jQuery just use .data(); eg: $(this).data('ksm');

Comment: `total = total + Number( $(this).data('ksm') );` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method

```
   $(window).load(function(){
    $("[id$=nr]").change(function() {
        var total = 0;     
        $('.zawodnik select').each(function() {
            var option = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
            total = total + parseFloat( $(option).data('ksm') );
        });
        $('div#sumaksm').html(total); 
    });
   });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bxuCw/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use '.attr()'

```
$(this).attr('data-ksm')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    $('#sumaksm').text(self.find('option:selected').data('ksm'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aQjbE/).

Though if you really *do* (for some reason) want to sum the `data-ksm` attribute every time the `select` changes:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        total = 0;
    self.find('option').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).data('ksm'));
    });
    $('#sumaksm').text(total);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aQjbE/1/).

Following Gaby's hint (in comments, below), I'd suggest:

```
$('[id$=nr]').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('[id$=nr]').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).find('option:selected').data('ksm'));
    });
    $('#sumaksm').text(total);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aQjbE/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).